# Unity / Passing an array in a shader

Tags: unity, shaders

I want to pass my array (which is inside my c# code) to my shader.

```
Shader "custom/shader4" 
{
    Properties
    {
        _myArray("Array", Float[256]) = []
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            public float _myArray[256];

//code...
```

^this is obviously not working. Is anyone here who knows how to solve this?

(also in c#:)

```
myMaterial.MyArray = anotherArray;
```

It has to be something like this- right?
Or do I need a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this has too many views, here is the obvious answer:

First you need to assign this in your C# Script:

```
public Material myMaterial;

void Update()
{
//or somewhere else
MyMaterial.SetFloatArray("_FloatArrayNameInsideShader", MyFloatArray);

}
```

Then in your Shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Array" {
     Properties {
...
     }
     SubShader {
         Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
         LOD 200

         CGPROGRAM
         #pragma target 3.0
...

         float _FloatArrayNameInsideShader[3];
 ....
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you need to use 5.4 Beta in order to do this at the moment.

Take a look at:

http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material.SetFloatArray.html

Or the other SetArray methods of the Material class, starting from 5.4.

http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Material.html

Comment: Were now at 5.6, perhaps this answer could be updated?